# Is there a way to make my code functions work for multiple variables instead of the one i currently have it working for?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks as follows (with around 200 individuals):

```
NAME AGE2012 SEX   SurveyDate12 WAZ12 BAZ12 HAZ12 HB12 SurveyDate14 WAZ14 BAZ14 HAZ14 HB14
1      22    Male   2012-11-26  -1.2 -0.54 -0.01 11.9  2014-11-26  -1.5  -0.52 -0.43 12.2
2      26    Female 2012-11-26  -1.5 -0.36 -0.04 11.2  2014-11-26  -1.7  -0.84 -0.32 11.4
```

I Am currently using them to make a slopegraph, so I have to do certain things with this dataset such as using pivot longer. I am practising to use factors, and so am trying to keep everything I do within a function. I have the code working to make the graph using just HB (see below). But what I would like to do is make this code work for all 4 of the variables I have in my dataset just using functions. Can anyone help me with this?

```
slopegraph_prep <- function(health_longer, HB){health %>%
  select(NAME:SEX, starts_with("HB")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("HB"),
               names_to = "Year",
               names_prefix = "HB",
               values_to = "HB") %>%
  mutate(
    HB = case_when(
      HB < 0        ~ "NA",
      TRUE ~ as.character(HB) 
    )
  )  %>%
  na_if("NA") %>% 
  mutate(HB = as.numeric(HB)) %>%

  mutate(
    Year = case_when(
      Year=="12" ~ "2012",
      Year=="14" ~ "2014",
      Year=="19" ~ "2019")
  )
}



slopegraph_by_sex <- function(health, HB, SEX){ Subsetdata <- subset(health, SEX == SEX)
newggslopegraph(Subsetdata , Year , HB, NAME,
                Title = "Haemoglobin", 
                SubTitle = SEX, 
                Caption = NULL,
                RemoveMissing = FALSE)
 }

df_healthmeas <- slopegraph_prep(health, "HB")


df_healthmeas_female <- slopegraph_by_sex(df_healthmeas, "Haemoglobin", "female")

df_healthmeas_male <- slopegraph_by_sex(df_healthmeas, "Haemoglobin", "male")
```

What I really want to do is to just be able to run this for example and for it to run, but I feel I will need to make my variables more generic?:

```
   df_healthmeas <- slopegraph_prep(health, "WAZ")
    df_healthmeas_female <- slopegraph_by_sex(df_healthmeas, "Weight to Age WAZ", "female") 
df_healthmeas_male <- slopegraph_by_sex(df_healthmeas, "Weight to Age WAZ", "male")
```

Any help with this would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is already doable with your code, you olny have to specify the function argument:

```
df_healthmeas <- slopegraph_prep(health_longer = health, HB =WAZ)
```

the variables you specified in the fiunction code is only a "dummy" so you could re-write it for better readabiliy as such:

```
slopegraph_prep <- function(data, var){data %>%
  select(NAME:SEX, starts_with("var")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("var"),
               names_to = "Year",
               names_prefix = "var",
               values_to = "var") %>%
  mutate(
    var = case_when(
      var < 0        ~ "NA",
      TRUE ~ as.character(var) 
    )
  )  %>%
  na_if("NA") %>% 
  mutate(var = as.numeric(var)) %>%

  mutate(
    Year = case_when(
      Year=="12" ~ "2012",
      Year=="14" ~ "2014",
      Year=="19" ~ "2019")
  )
}
```

Comment: So I changed my code to this  based on your reply and then ran this row -> 

df_healthmeas <- slopegraph_prep(health, "WAZ")

 and it came back saying 

 Error: `cols` must select at least one column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. 

can you help with this at all sorry?